# Estimating Parameters of Log-Concave Model

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, regression, least-squares, parameter-estimation

I'm considering the problem of fitting some given data,

$(x_1,y_1), (x_2, y_2), \dots (x_m,y_m)$,

with a log-concave function,

$y = (\alpha x)^\beta$.

Parameters that I want to estimate are $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
I tried least-squares method on the log of data:

$min. \|\log(y) - \beta(\log(\alpha) + \log(x))\|_2^2$,

but this doesn't seem to be a convex problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: On the log of the data this is just linear regression. What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Parameters are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and the log is not linear with respect to them (there is $\beta \log(\alpha)$ term).

Comment: You want to fit $\log y \approx \beta \log \alpha + \beta \log x = c + \beta \log x$, where $c = \beta \log \alpha$. This is linear regression. Fit $\beta$ and $c$ first, then set $\alpha = \exp(c/\beta)$.